# In Python FastAPI, Is it possible to inject dependencies to the path operations conditionally

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi

I'm quite new to the Python FastAPI, I searched in the FastAPI documentation, blogs and Stack Overflow but couldn't find the precise answer to this question -

**Is it possible to conditionally inject dependencies in  the path operations?**

For example:
Based on environmental variable `Enable_Auth`=True or False, I should be able to enable or disable the Auth dependencies on path operations

Any support is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use a check within the dependency? Have you tried already?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that could be an option but I want to avoid dependency injection itself otherwise for every API call I need to check the condition

Comment: You said that you want to use dependency injection in your question. Have you changed your mind?

Comment: I didn't change my mind, I want to use dependency injection but based on the environment variable value. For example if enable_auth=true, then only I want to pass dependencies to the path operation otherwise avoid injecting dependencies to the path operation

Comment: You said you `want to avoid dependency injection itself`. You cannot conditionally add them based on the request. Either you do a check within the dependency itself or you don't use the dependency.

Comment: As mentioned that decision would need to be made by some code - i.e. by the dependency. What I usually do is to have one `authenticated_router = APIRouter(dependencies=[this_dependency_verifies_if_a_user_is_authenticated])` and one that is `unauthenticated_router = APIRouter()`, and then register the given endpoint / subrouters under those. That way you don't end up forgetting a dependency and repeating code in each endpoint definition. This also makes it easy to fake authentication in any tests.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try the approach mentioned by @MatsLindh

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can inject conditional dependency with a trick like this:

```py
from typing import Annotated
import os
from fastapi import Depends

async def dep_func_for_Auth(*args, **kwargs)-> type1:
...

async def dep_func_for_withoutAuth(*args, **kwargs)-> type2:
...

useAuth = os.environ.get("Enable_Auth")

dependency = Annotated[type1 if useAuth else type2,
Depends(dep_func_for_Auth if useAuth else dep_func_for_withoutAuth) 
]
```

then you can inject this dependency to any path operation function like this:

```py
@app.get("/anypath")
async def pathOperationSample(dep: dependency):
...
```